# How to run python script from command line or from another script

Tags: python

I downloaded a script written in Python, called let's say 'myScript.py', but I don't know how to run it.
It has the following structure:

```
import numpy as np
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='manual to this script')
parser.add_argument('--file', type=str, default = None)
parser.add_argument('--timeCor', type=bool, default = False)
parser.add_argument('--iteration', type=str, default = 'Newton')
args = parser.parse_args()


def func1(file):
...

def func2(file):
...

def calculate(data, timeCor=False, iteration='Newton'):
...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('\n--- Calculating ---\nN file:',args.file)
    print('Time correction =',args.timeCor,
          '\nIteration strategy =',args.iteration,'\n')
    
    rawdata,data = func2(args.file)
    pos = calculate(data,timeCor=args.timeCor,iteration=args.iteration)
    for each in pos:
        print('Pos:',format(np.uint8(each[0]),'2d'),each[1:-1])
    np.savetxt('pos.csv',pos,delimiter=',')
    print('--- Save file as "pos.csv" in the current directory ---')
```

How can I run it from command line? And from another script?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Run it by executing:

```
python myScript.py
```

Alternatively, on systems which support it (UNIX-Like systems), you can add what's called a she-bang to the first line of the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Note that `/usr/bin/python` should be the actual path where your python is located. After that, make the file executable:

```
chmod u+x myScript.py
```

and run it either from the current directory:

```
./myScript.py
```

or from a different directory with full or relative path:

```
/path/to/python/scripts/myScript.py
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you are asking about executing this python program from another python script. This can be done by making use of `subprocess`.

```py
import subprocess

process = subprocess.run([“python3”, “path-to-myScript.py”, “command line arguments here”], capture_output=True)
output = process.stdout.decode() # stdout is bytes

print(output)
```

If you do not want to provide the command in a list, you can add `shell=True` as an argument to `subprocess.run()`, or you can use `shlex.split()`.

If you are on windows, replace `python3` with `python`.

**However** this solution is not very portable, and on a more general note, if you are not strictly needing to *run* the script, I would recommend you to import it and call its functions directly instead.

To run the python script from command line:

```
python myScript.py --arguments
```

And as @treuss has said, if you are on a Unix system (macOS or Linux) you can add a `shebang` to the top of the script, but I recommend to use the following instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

for portability sake, as the actual path of `python3` may vary.

To run the edited program:

```
chmod +x myScript # to make file executable, and note that there is no longer a .py extension as it is not necessary
./myScript --arguments
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanationi. However if I try to execute from command line, I get the following error: _SyntaxError: invalid syntax, TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression_

I tried both the following:

python myScript.py --file="fileName.fileExtension"

Comment: @eljamba did you get the error from running `myScript.py` or running the other script that is running `myScript.py` using subprocess?

Comment: the first one you said, I tried _python myScript.py --file="fileName.fileExt"_ and the same command with python3 instead

Comment: That would be an issue with the script itself. Maybe you can post a separate question regarding this issue.